# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'users.txt'

Tags: python, io

I am getting the above error when I use a webserver to run my code, however locally in the Terminal this works fine. I believe this must be to do with the path to the file working locally but not remotely. I have seen the solution on stackoverflow is to add the filepath like '/user/xxx/library/' etc, however is there a solution that allows this to be system agnostic? As in if I copy this directory to another location/server it will still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import `os`, it's built it to Python. You can get teh absolute path of the .py file this way:

```
import os
ROOT = lambda base : os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), base).replace('\\','/')
```

Now you can simply do the following:

```
ROOT('users.txt')
```

It should return the absolute path.

Comment: Yes it should work, the path is not hardcoded so it'll generate the absolute path.

Comment: I suggest to replace `base` with `relPath`. And is the `replace()` of backslash necessary? Even if your OS uses backslash, `os.path.join()` should work fine.